# A file icon package is not working on sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I downloaded the 'A file icon' package through package control -> install package -> a file icon.
It downloaded successfully and the package is available in list of packages but for some reason I cant view the icons of the files on my sidebar.How do I rectify this?[A screenshot of my sublimetext with sidebar without the file icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLbUV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A File Icon` only displays icons for files that are in folders in the sidebar. For example, if you select **`File → Open Folder…`** and choose a folder, any files in that folder (and subfolders) will have an icon displayed next to them, once they have been indexed.